# In C#, how do you declare an array with all values set to zero, without explicitly declaring it?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, 2d

What I am trying to do is something like this (in c#):

```
int[,] arr2d = {
                      {0, 0},
                      {0, 0},
                      {0, 0}
                  };
```

This produces an array that is 2 columns wide and 3 rows in length with all values set to zero.

What I am trying to do is something such that i can initialize an array where I give a value `x` for width, and a value `y` for height, which will declare a 2d array of those specifications of which all values are zero.

Essentially, how do I make a 2d array where all values are zero of any height and width WITHOUT declaring each one individually as in the code above.

Comment: Note that it is generally not _possible_ to have uninitialized variables or arrays in C#. They either get automatically initialized or it is a compile-time error if you don't initialize them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 is a default int value, so you can do the same by this code

```
var arr2d = new int[3,2];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill an Array other than the default value, you can use Fill,

```
Array.Fill(arrayToFill, value)
```

To reset filled array to default value (eg: in int array to reset to 0)

```
Array.Clear(arrayToReset, 0, arrayToReset.Length);
```